With RCF-3.3.470 getting Configuration mismatch linker error during RcfInit function call
Working on client-server model and getting linker error as Configuration mismatch during RcfInit function call.
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: RCF::RcfInit::RcfInit(RCF::RcfConfigurationDetectMismatches<1, 0, 1, 1>*)                                                                                                           
>>> referenced by RcfInitializer.cpp:930 (/extra/build/rcfinit-px2_rcf_init_arch_armv7_variant_tp/RcfInitializer.cpp:930)                                                                                                  
>>>               RcfInitializer.cpp.o:(RcfInitializer::RcfInitializer()) in archive build/sandboxes/px2_rcf_init_arch_armv7_variant_tp/lib/libpx2_rcf_init.a                                                                               
>>> did you mean: RCF::RcfInit::RcfInit(RCF::RcfConfigurationDetectMismatches<1, 0, 0, 1>*)                                                                                                                                                 
>>> defined in: ~/.cache/jolt/linux_sdk/main@4987f42f712e224cf33647ec4703b2e278a2890f/sysroots/armv7ahf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/11.4.0/../../../lib/librcf.so      

As from RCF/Config.hpp file, we have to enable file transfer, internal serialization and protobuf due to which config becomes <1,0,1,1>.
Snippet from RCF/Config.hpp:
    typedef RcfConfigurationDetectMismatches<
        RcfConfig_SF::value, 
        RcfConfig_BSer::value, 
        RcfConfig_FileTransfer::value,
        RcfConfig_Protobufs::value>                     RcfConfigT;

In RCF-2.0 default config was <1,0,0,1>. Any support will be appreciated.
I had tried to see all the location where default config is setting and make sure that my config will be as per RCF.3.3.470 version.

Make sure that you have the same set of RCF_XXX defines, defined across all the source code you're building, and that you're compiling all your source code (libs as well as executables) against the same version of RCF.
